# listview item is not displaying the assigned value in getview method of custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I ran into a problem and still don't know how to get out. I made a listview with a custom adapter for it. I also implemented a searchview which will update the listview everytime I type in a character. But the problem is that the listview is not showing the correct results. I put some checkpoints in `getView` method of the custom adapter to check if the values which will be displayed are right or not and they're all right.

[image]

I have two items, let's call them HD03 and HD02 as you can see their name on the top left corner of each item.

when I type in the search bar `02`, the result must be item `HD02` but I got item `HD03` instead. Although, the value I checked in the `getView` method using debugger was `HD02`

[image]

I think I made a silly mistake somewhere but I can't find it. Thank you for your time !
Here're my fragment and my adapter code.

Fragment

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
    private ListView listViewContract;
    private SearchView contractSearchView;
    private ContractAdapter productListAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        initView(root);

        return root;
    }

    private void initView(View view) {
        listViewContract = view.findViewById(R.id.contract_list);
        listViewContract.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                listViewProduct_onItemClick(adapterView, view, i, l);
            }
        });

        loadData();

        contractSearchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        contractSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                DashboardFragment.this.productListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                DashboardFragment.this.productListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadData() {
        List<Contract> products = new ArrayList<Contract>();
        products.add(new Contract("p03", "Name 1", "4", "Mới", "HD03" ));
        products.add(new Contract("p02", "Name 2", "5", "Mới", "HD02"));
        productListAdapter = new ContractAdapter(getContext(), products);
        listViewContract.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
    }

    private void listViewProduct_onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
//        Product product = (Product) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), product.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ContractAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private List<Contract> products;
    private List<Contract> filteredData;
    private ItemFilter itemFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public ContractAdapter(Context context, List<Contract> products){
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
        this.filteredData = products;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.phan_anh_cardview, parent, false);
            viewHolder.textViewContractName = view.findViewById(R.id.ten_hd);
            viewHolder.textViewCustomerName = view.findViewById(R.id.ten_dt);
            viewHolder.textViewEmployeeName = view.findViewById(R.id.ten_nv);
            viewHolder.textViewId = view.findViewById(R.id.ma_hd);
            viewHolder.buttonStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.report_status);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        Contract product = filteredData.get(position);
        viewHolder.textViewContractName.setText(product.getName());
        viewHolder.textViewEmployeeName.setText(product.getNhanvien());
        viewHolder.textViewCustomerName.setText(product.getCustomer());
        viewHolder.textViewId.setText(product.get_id());
        viewHolder.buttonStatus.setText(product.getStatus());

        Log.i("view", viewHolder.textViewId.getText().toString());

        return view;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Contract getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return itemFilter;
//        return super.getFilter();
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public static TextView textViewContractName;
        public static TextView textViewCustomerName;
        public static TextView textViewEmployeeName;
        public static TextView textViewId;
        public static Button buttonStatus;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String query = constraint.toString();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<Contract> originalData = products;
            int count = originalData.size();
            List<Contract> nList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Contract contract : originalData) {
                if(contract.get_id().contains(query) || contract.getName().contains(query) || contract.getCustomer().contains(query)){
                    nList.add(contract);
                }
            }

            results.values = nList;
            results.count = nList.size();

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (List<Contract>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/tag_spinner_constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tag_spinner_constraint"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tag_spinner_constraint"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tag_spinner_constraint" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/filter_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_bar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/empty_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="99dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Phòng trống"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor_spinner" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/not_full_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Phòng ghép"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/empty_rooms_btn"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor_spinner" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/full_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Phòng đã đầy"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/not_full_rooms_btn"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor_spinner" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/all_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Tất cả"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contract_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tag_spinner_constraint">


    </ListView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

phan_anh_cardview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="162dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="6dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/report_status"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:text="Mới"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ma_hd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ten_hd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ma_hd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ten_dt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ten_hd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ten_nv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ten_dt" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

rounded_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Could you post xml also, then i will debug your code in my env.

Comment: I updated my question with all necessary xml code. Thank you in advance !

Comment: I post answer, please check it.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag. This tag is for questions/problems related to the Android Studio product. This is a generic Android question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found error in your code.
You shouldn't use static members in ViewHolder.
So please replace ViewHolder code as following.

ContractAdapter.java

```
..............

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewContractName;
    public TextView textViewCustomerName;
    public TextView textViewEmployeeName;
    public TextView textViewId;
    public Button buttonStatus;
}

...............
```

If so, it will be working.

Comment: Oh ! Thank you so much, I reused this code from an older project and I didn't notice this. It's been a while since the last time I worked on an android project. Thank you !